# Install package failed because of dependency problem

Tags: package, centos7, sudo, rpm, yum

to update a package with yum or rpm the install failed because of a dependency issue

```
rpm -ivh sudo-1.8.29-6.el8_3.1.x86_64.rpm 
warning: sudo-1.8.29-6.el8_3.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY

error: Failed dependencies:
```

libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit) is needed by sudo-1.8.29-6.el8_3.1.x86_64

```
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.26)(64bit) is needed by sudo-1.8.29-6.el8_3.1.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) is needed by sudo-1.8.29-6.el8_3.1.x86_64
```

but libc.so.6 exists

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 Mar 11 01:01 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.17.so

Is there anyone who can help me to solve this problem?

With kind regards, Wil

Answer (score 1):

The existing of libc.so.6 doesnot means required version.
use linux command "strings" to dig what the max supported version of current library is.

like this:

```
⋊> /h/m/stackoverfolw strings /lib64/libc.so.6  | grep GLIBC                                                                                                                                                                                            
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
```

This example shows the max supported version is GLIBC_2.17.

In the same way you should use the right libc.so including version GLIBC_2.27.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I executed the command and i get exactly the same output...also GLIBC_2.17 is the max. So i downloaded and tried to install glibc-2.28-127.el8.x86_64.rpm (which must contain GLIBC_2.27), but glibc-common.... is needed. i installed glibc-common and this one failed, because glibc-2.28 is needed and so on. What should i do?

Comment: You need install the latest glibc (or satisfy your minimum version). Here is the optional items. complile from gcc source and make soft link replacing /lib64/libc.so.6. Or else install third environment like "scl environment" which supply newer version.